# Spring Boot multi-tenant API gateway: how to handle multiple sessions

Tags: java, spring-boot, multi-tenant

I'm creating an API Gateway that supports multi-tenancy.

I'll explain things through an example:

I call */tenant/tenant-1-id/test-endpoint* from the browser, and this triggers a log in in Keycloak (can be any OpenId compatible).

After entering username and password, I'm correctly logged in and get a response  with some text. It doesn't matter what for this example.

Now I call */tenant/**tenant-2-id**/test-endpoint* from the browser, and:

**Expectation:** I'm prompted to log in again, and from here on I can both call */tenant/tenant-1-id/test-endpoint* and */tenant/tenant-2-id/test-endpoint* without logging in again.

**Actual:** Log in is not triggered and the endpoint returns a response.

I know that the problem resides in the same cookie/session being used for both calls, but I'm not quite sure how to proceed.

**TenantContext.java:**

```
@Slf4j
public final class TenantContext {

    private TenantContext() {}

    private static InheritableThreadLocal<TenantInfo> currentTenant = new InheritableThreadLocal<>();

    public static void setTenantInfo(TenantInfo tenantId) {
        log.info("Setting tenantId to " + tenantId);
        currentTenant.set(tenantId);
    }

    public static TenantInfo getTenantInfo() {
        return currentTenant.get();
    }

    public static void clear(){
        currentTenant.remove();
    }
}
```

**TenantInfo.java:**

```
@ToString
@Getter
@Builder
class TenantInfo {
    private String url;
    private int port;
    private String realm;
    private String clientId; // Should be the name of the service, the same for all realms
    private String secret;
}
```

**WebConfiguration.java:**

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final TenantInterceptor tenantInterceptor;

    @Autowired
    public WebConfiguration(TenantInterceptor tenantInterceptor) {
        this.tenantInterceptor = tenantInterceptor;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addWebRequestInterceptor(tenantInterceptor);
    }

}
```

**TenantInterceptor.java:**

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class TenantInterceptor implements WebRequestInterceptor {

    private final static Map<String, TenantInfo> idToIss = Map.of(
        "bank1-id",
        TenantInfo.builder()
            .url("...")
            .port(...)
            .realm("...")
            .clientId("...")
            .secret("...")
            .build(),
        "bank2-id",
        TenantInfo.builder()
            .url("...")
            .port(...)
            .realm("...")
            .clientId("...")
            .secret("...")
            .build()
    );

    @Override
    public void preHandle(WebRequest request) throws Exception {

        final String path = ((DispatcherServletWebRequest) request).getRequest().getServletPath(); // E.G. "/tenant/bank2-id/test"

        if (path.equals("/error")) {
            log.warn("Error was detected. Bypassing TenantInterceptor."); // TODO: Implement proper handling for errors
            return;
        }

        final String[] pieces = path.split("/");
        if (pieces.length < 4 || !pieces[1].equals("tenant")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid path. It should be '/tenant/{id}/*' but was '" + path + "'");
        }
        final String tenantId = pieces[2];
        final TenantInfo tenantInfo = idToIss.get(tenantId);
        if (tenantInfo == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Tenant " + tenantId + " does not exist");
        }

        TenantContext.setTenantInfo(tenantInfo);
    }


    @Override
    public void postHandle(WebRequest request, ModelMap model) throws Exception {
        TenantContext.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(WebRequest request, Exception ex) throws Exception {
    }

}
```

**Maven dependencies:**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Of course the TenantInterceptor is super working in progress. Mapping id to ISS won't be stored in memory, but in a Spring Config Server, meaning that the tenants can be added or removed at any given time. But this is just an hint for you.

I think that I'm in the right track to archieve what I want to do. I just need a little help to solve the log in issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think that in your case, the easiest way to achieve what you want is to deploy a gateway for each tenant:

- one gateway instance (configured as OAuth2 client) responsible for `/tenant/tenant-1-id/**`
- another gateway (configured as OAuth2 client too) for `/tenant/tenant-2-id/**`
- a 3rd gateway (without any OAuth2 configuration) or an ingress, a load-balancer, or whatever, to route requests to the right tenant specific gateway

I believe that you hit the same kind of limitation as the one I reported in [this ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12862): a spring application with `oauth2Login` is a client and current Spring Security implementation for OAuth2 clients is very single-tenant, and it's not just a matter of session: all the stack (`OAuth2AuthenticationToken` which is the `Authentication` implementation for OAuth2 clients, but also `OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository`) was designed with the idea that a user is limited to a single identity at a time: a single `subject` in a claim-set issued by a single authorization server. This design decision is reflected between the lines if you read the comments in the [pull request for Back-Channel Logout](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/pull/12570) which, I bet, will be limited to single tenant scenarios too.

The thing is that, alone, I am not considered seriously enough to have any influence on Spring teams design decisions and it's pretty unlikely that multi tenancy for OAuth2 clients is something they get interested in anytime soon. Would you please elaborate on why you need the different identities for a single user session and comment on the ticket I opened?

Comment: Hi @ch4mp!

Thanks for sharing your ticket. Damn, that explain why I was so lost not finding a fitting solution...

I tried your code, marking it as a @Component, and your code is called on the first login. I was able to debug it and I'll play around with it. Better than being completely lost 

However, I noticed that I won't be prompted to log in with the second tenant, nor your code will be proc'ed in your case. Is this intended?

Comment: By the way, having multiple gateways is a no-go at the moment because having only one is a requirement. We don't want specific istances being run for specific customers. I hope, you can help working around the problem.

Comment: I really hope, we can help also other people with similar issues with this thread.

Comment: **you really should write down why you need a user to be authenticated against several tenants at the same time** : this is precisely because people don't think it is useful that it is no implemented. I think that you should change your mind about your requirement: if you read my answer again, you'll see that there is a single entrypoint, the per-tenant gateways acting behind this single entry-point.

Comment: The code I reported in the ticket makes it possible to store (and retrieve) more than one identity at a time for a single user in a spring OAuth2 client. It does not trigger new loggins, you still have to implement that part. you might have a look at my [resource-server_with_uil](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_ui) tutoria which demoes the usage of several simultaneous identities for a single user.